# How to generate 2D normal random variables in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I need a matlab program to generate a 2D normal random variable in matlab. Kindly help me.

Comment: are you looking for [rand(rowNum, columnNum)](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html)?

Comment: No, I want to generate some random numbers (say 50 combination of x and y) around a cordinate (x,y)

Comment: `rand(50, 2) + [2, 1]` will give you 50 random numbers around (2, 1). Is this what you want? If not, please clarify your prerequisites: type of random distribution, ...

Comment: The random distribution should be gaussian .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `randn` and `bsxfun(@plus,xy,d)` (or just `xy + d` in newer MATLAB versions:

```
% original coordinates
xy = [1,4];
% random deviations
n = 50;
SIGMA = 0.5; % deviation sigma
d = randn(n,2)*SIGMA;
% add deviations to original xy
XY = bsxfun(@plus,xy,d);
```

Comment: which kind of of distribution it will be?

Comment: @RohitKumar Normal?

Comment: normal distribution with 0 mean and `SIGMA` standard deviation

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [`mvnrnd`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnrnd.html) function.

You can call it like so:

```
X = mvnrnd([4, 5], [1, 0; 0, 1], 50);
%          ^^ mean   ^^ sigma   ^^ how many points to generate
```

Comment: But, how can I generate 50 2D-points, using mvnrand function? However,The distribution should be Gaussian.

Comment: I've fixed a few syntax errors in your code, such as the function name.  Also note that the function relies on the Statistics Toolbox and does not come standard with MATLAB (i.e. requires purchasing).

Comment: @RohitKumar you just need to add a third parameter. All this info and more you can find out in the link I posted.

Comment: @RohitKumar `mvnrnd` comes from a Normal (a.k.a. Gaussian) distribution.  You should really do what Horia says and read the documentation.  Many problems get solved by simply reading on how to use the functions suggested here.